# Rails form: A field showing the value of one variable but saving it to another variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have an edit form with the profile data for a user. Two variables in the User table are `email` and `new_email`. I would like for one of the fields in the edit form to *show* a user's `email` but if a new value is entered in that field, I would like it to not *save* to `email` but instead to `new_email`. So I think I need a form field for `new_email` that however shows the value of `email`. How should I adjust my code below to achieve this?

I currently have in my view:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :new_email, class: 'form-control' %>     #!!Relevant line.

<%= f.label :other_fields_like_this %>
<%= f.text_field :other_fields_like_this, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(userupdate_params)
    if params[:user][:new_email] != @user.email   # That is, if: a new email address is entered, i.e. a value other then the existing value for email is entered
      #save value to new_email instead of to email. How to do this?
       send_confirmation_email
       flash[:success] = "Your email address has not yet been updated. Please check your email for a confirmation link."
       redirect_to @user
     end
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def userupdate_params
    params.require(:user).permit(#:email,  #email I think can be removed here, since it's new_email whose value will change.
                                 :new_email,
                                 :other_fields_like_this,
                                 :password, 
                                 :password_confirmation)
end
```

Just to give some background information: after this I intend to expand this with a confirmation email. If the user clicks the confirmation link, then the value of `new_email` will overwrite the `email` value. So therefore I want it to initially save to `new_email` and only later, upon confirmation, to `email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply a default value to an input field:

`<%= f.email_field :new_email, value: @user.email, class: 'form-control' %>`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Had to change the controller to: `if params[:user][:new_email] != @user.email` `see post` `else` `flash[:success] = "Profile updated"` `redirect_to @user` `end`.

Comment: There proofs to be one problem, after all. It also tries to save to `new_email` even when the value in that field has not changed. This causes problems with the validations that I have. Is there a way to change this so that it only tries to write to `new_email` if a value other than the existing value for `@user.email` is entered? Perhaps I should move the line `if params[:user][:new_email] != @user.email` one line higher?

Comment: Using different strong params for when a new email address is entered (then strong params include new_email) and when not (then it doesn't include new_email and therefore doesn't execute validation), solved it

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way.  You can still look at it, but filter it out from being saved to db.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a `before_update` callback and assign it's value to the `new_email` field.